# using signals to create a model?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, signals

I have instructor and club models. I want when an instructor who is a supervisor is created, he/she will be assigned to a club that is equal to his/her department. I'm new to signals and not sure how to achieve it?

models.py

```
class Instructor(models.Model):
    dep_choice = (
        (0, 'ISOM'),
        (1, 'Accounting'),
        (2, 'PA'),
        (3, 'Finance'),
        (4, 'Management & Marketing'),
        (5, 'Economics'),
    )
    instructor_user = models.OneToOneField(MyUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    department = models.IntegerField(choices=dep_choice, default=0)
    supervisor = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def __str__(self):
       return str(self.instructor_user)    

class Club(models.Model):
    ISOM = 0
    Accounting = 1
    PA = 2
    Finance = 3
    ManagementandMarketing = 4
    Economics = 5
    club_name = (
        (ISOM, 'ISOM'),
        (Accounting, 'Accounting'),
        (PA, 'PA'),
        (Finance, 'Finance'),
        (ManagementandMarketing, 'Management & Marketing'),
        (Economics, 'Economics'),

    )
    instructor = models.OneToOneField(Instructor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.IntegerField(choices=club_name, default=0)
    def __str__(self):
       return self.get_name_display()
```

signals.py

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Instructor, Student, Adminstrator, MyUser, Club

@receiver(post_save, sender=Instructor)
def post_save_create_instructor(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
  if created:
    if instance.supervisor == True:
       Club.objects.create(instructor=instance)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your logic looks like it does what you want, so the problem **might** be somewhere else - Django requires a few other things to make sure that signals do work!

Besides having the `@receiver` (which you have!), make sure that:

- The `__init__.py` file of your Django app contains the line: `default_app_config = 'yourmodule.apps.YourModuleConfig'`
- Inside the Django app that harbours both these files, the `apps.py` file's `AppConfig` class imports the signals!

Here's an example that'll illustrate the aforementioned points:

```py
# customers/__init__.py
default_app_config = "customers.apps.CustomerConfig"
```

```
# customers/apps.py
from django.apps import AppConfig

class CustomersConfig(AppConfig):
   name = "customers"

   def ready(self):
      import customers.signals
```

```py
# customers/models.py
from django.db import models

class Customer(models.Model):
   ...
```

```py
# customers/signals.py

@receiver(post_save, sende=Customer)
def do_something_when_customer_gets_created(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

did you configure the signals in your app.py?

for example:

```py
from django.apps import AppConfig


class InstructorConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'instructor'

    def ready(self) -> None:
        import instructor.signals
```

Test it!